# importing JSON to google sheets gives getRrange-error

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having troubles importing json data to google spreadsheets using google script. I have no java knowledge so sorry if the question is a bit stupid! 
I do code a bit of VBA so I'm not completely unaccustomed to code.

I'm trying to pull the live exchange-rate from a cryptocurrency-exchange's API. I managed to get it to work with a different exchange's API, but here the json looks slightly different.

The JSON I can't get into google spreadsheets looks like this;
`{"success":true,"message":"","result":{"Bid":0.00011437,"Ask":0.00011447,"Last":0.00011447}}`
I have checked json on https://jsonlint.com/ and it checks out ok.

The code I use is this;

```
 1 function pullJSON_XRP() {
 2 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 3 var sheets = ss.getSheets();
 4 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 5 Logger.log(sheets)
 6 var url="https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=BTC-XRP"; // JSON call URL 
 7 
 8 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
 9 var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 
10 var dataSet = dataAll;
11 Logger.log(dataSet)
12 var rows = [],
13 data;
14 Logger.log(rows)
15 
16 for (i = 0; i < dataSet.rows; i++) {
17 data = dataSet[i];
18 rows.push(data.result.Bid, data.result.Ask, data.result.Last); //JSON entities
19 }
20 
21 dataRange = sheet.getRange(3, 1, rows.length, 3); // 4th Denotes total number of entites
22 dataRange.setValues(rows);
23 }
```

I get an error on row 21. The error message is in Swedish and remains in Swedish even though I changed my language on google but it reads something like: "Range coordinates or size invalid. At first at thought this was because `dataRange = sheet.getRange(3, 1, rows.length, 3);` mismatched the array for some reason. I have spent hours searching and testing but to no avail. I now suspect that my parsed json isn't being addressed correctly in `rows.push(data.result.Bid, data.result.Ask, data.result.Last);`

I have tried just using the ids `data.Bid, data.Ask, data.Last` but I still get the same error.

Any help would be so appreciated! =)

Thank you for taking the time!

Humbly,

Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple way:

```
 function pullJSON_XRP() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheets = ss.getSheets();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var url="https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=BTC-XRP"; // JSON call URL 
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
 var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 
 var values=[[ dataAll.result.Bid,dataAll.result.Ask,dataAll.result.Last]]
 sheet.getRange("A3:C3").setValues(values)
 }
```